# Using Sugar To Create Candy Machine for NFT Launch

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine, solana-cli

I have been going through the Sugar CLI for the first time and was hoping to clarify a couple of things to make sure I am creating the Candy Machine correctly. It's clear from the documentation (https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/configuration) that the `creators` wallet should now be added to the Candy Machine config file.

But where should `sellerFeeBasisPoints` and `collection` properies go? Does it hurt anything if they are present on both the config file and each metadata file?

For the collection property - is this taken care of with the new `collection.json` and `collection.png`? Does this need to be present at all on either the config or the metadata file?

Appreciate any clarifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sellerFeeBasisPoints` goes into the configuration file, like creators.

It doesnt hurt anyone if they are present on both metadata and config, but the one inside the metadata wont matter at all because its deprecated, the important is the one inside the config file.

`collections` is managed with `collection.json` and `collection.png`, you dont need to set anything extra on metadata or config file, you just need the collection metadata and collection image, so sugar will deploy this metadata into the selected storage, then will create and mint ur collection NFT and finally will attach that collection NFT publicKey to all NFTs that will be minted from the created candy machine. If you dont provide the `collection.json` and `collection.png`, then you will have to create and mint the collection NFT by yourself and then manually add that collection to each minted NFT that doesnt have a collection attached.